# generate dynamic page in HTML from xml

Tags: java, html, xml, jsp, xslt

I have several different XML files. I want to display them in HTML format using JSP file. 
The structure of these files can be different. They may have different depth and tag's names.
I've read about XSLT but I found only examples with manually created xsl. (I can't do that because i will have many different xml files).

How can i produce my html?

**EDIT**:

Example of form:

```
<form name="Company">
               <field name="name" required="true" type="inputText"/>
               <field name="registrationDate" required="true" type="date"/>
               <field name="isActive" required="false" type="boolean"/>
               <field name="unregistrationDate" type="date"/>
               <field name="type" type="comboBox">
                              <values>
                                             <value>type1</value>
                                             <value>type3</value>
                                             <value>type3</value>
                              </values>
                              <defaultSelected>type2</defaultSelected>
               </field>
</form>
```

Comment: Any example of how your XML files do look like, and how should the desired HTML output look like?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek please look at my comment

Comment: "*The structure of these files can be different.*" Your question tells us nothing about how different they can be, or what should they look like after being transformed. There's no "one size fits all" XSLT.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Ok, so i can't use XSLT. But still, what i need to do is to generate html based on xml, where xml files may have different depth.

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't use XSLT. I said your question is not well-defined.